# Issue with UUID datatype when laoding postgres table using Apache NiFi

Tags: postgresql, uuid, avro, apache-nifi

**Database**

- Postgres 9.6
- Contains several tables that have a UUID column (containing the ID of each record)

**NiFi**

- Latest release (1.7.1)
- Uses Avro 1.8.1 (as far as I know)

**Problem description**

When scheduling the tables using the ExecuteSQL processor, the following error message occurs:

> ExecuteSQL[id=09033e32-e840-1aed-3062-6e8cbc5551ba] ExecuteSQL[id=09033e32-e840-1aed-3062-6e8cbc5551ba] failed to process session due to createSchema: Unknown SQL type 1111 / uuid (table: country, column: id) cannot be converted to Avro type; Processor Administratively Yielded for 1 sec: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: createSchema: Unknown SQL type 1111 / uuid (table: country, column: id) cannot be converted to Avro type

Note that the flowfiles aren't removed from the incoming queue, nor sent to the 'failure' relationship, resulting in an endless loop of failing attempts.

**Attempts to fix issue**

- I tried enabling the *Use Avro Logical Types* property of the ExecuteSQL processor, but the same error occurred.

**Possible but not preferred solutions**

- I currently perform a SELECT * from each table. A possible solution (I think) would be to specify each column, and have the query cast the uuid to a string. Though this could work, I'd strongly prefer not having to list every column separately.

**A last note**

- I did find this Jira ticket: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/AVRO-1962
  However, I'm not sure how to interpret this. Is it implemented or not? Should it work or not?

Answer (score 1):

I believe UUID is not a standard JDBC type and is specific to Postgres.

The JDBC types class shows that SQL type 1111 is "OTHER":

```
 /**
     * The constant in the Java programming language that indicates
     * that the SQL type is database-specific and
     * gets mapped to a Java object that can be accessed via
     * the methods <code>getObject</code> and <code>setObject</code>.
     */
        public final static int OTHER           = 1111;
```

So I'm not sure how NiFi could know what to do here because it could be anything depending on the type of DB.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried creating a view where you define the column as ::text?

```
SELECT
    "v"."UUID_COLUMN"::text AS UUID_COLUMN
FROM
...
```

Comment: In the database lookup service, you can do the cast directly in the Lookup Key Column field.  I was able to cast a UUID column to string and perform a lookup with success.  There is no need to add a cast to the view.